# Xades4j - Unrecognized critical extension(s) in CRL

Tags: xades4j

I'm using xades4j to verify a Signature. The CRL has two critical extensions  (2.5.29.20, 2.5.29.35) and xades4j API reject the CRL.

**Exception that throw xades4j API:**

```
xades4j.providers.CannotBuildCertificationPathException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target  
xades4j.providers.impl.PKIXCertificateValidationProvider.validate(PKIXCertificateValidationProvider.java:268)  
xades4j.verification.XadesVerifierImpl.verify(XadesVerifierImpl.java:175)
```

How can I add an object identifier (OID) in xades4j?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR;: I don't think this is possible.

From the docs I was able to find, namely [Java PKI Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/certpath/CertPathProgGuide.html), additional OIDs can be handled using `PKIXCertPathChecker`. Currently, xades4j's [`PKIXCertificateValidationProvider`](https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j/blob/master/src/main/java/xades4j/providers/impl/PKIXCertificateValidationProvider.java) doesn't include a way to register new checkers.

Do you know any other way this could be done?